# How to design a phonographic sound filter in python?

Tags: filtering

I'm making a phonographic filter or simulator to make one of my songs to sound as if it was recorded on a phonographic cylinder.

Two important things about phonographic recoding is that sound gets more treble when it's louder and also that the recording of the wave is made top to bottom so the negative part of the wave will be more quiet than the positive part because the deeper the stylus goes in the wax higher the resistance of the wax also resulting in some a/c shift.

Also the wax of the recording material shouldn't be uniform having different height and hardness what generates the characteristic sound of silent. For the sake of noise generation I used this image of a cracked soap https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/close-up-cracked-dry-soap-surface-background-dehydrated-dry-skin-concept-close-up-cracked-dry-soap-surface-background-134542817.jpg and blurred it a little, because it's too cracked and converted to grayscale. I could use actual silent sound of a gramophone though.

Having the noise and the input signal, the next step is to shift the speed of the input, I'm not sure about the relations in the equations here but I made that the speed at any point to be inverse proportional to the sum of the of the signal and the noise (the signal makes the stylus to go deeper on the wax and the noise generates drag resitence as it's a measure of wax hardness, so it stops the electric engine), then I ac/shifted the signal to the negative peak (-1) and multiplied it by a factor of the noise (resistance to the stylus plunge) and then shifted it again to 0.

I obtained an acceptable sound (for the sake of purpose) after post processing the resulting signal by applying some noisegate, bandpass, overdrive and echo.

So how can I improve my algorithm and why did I need the post process? What are the physical processes implied in the the noisegating, bandpassing, and the other alterations of the phonographic sound?

Comment: @Tetsujin, DEFINITELY not vinyl that's 1960's, what I want is wax recording from 1920's and I doubt there's a plugin except for the one that I'm developping.

Comment: Then good luck with it - it's still not on-topic here.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I made the question here because I saw there was another post asking about how to make a diy phonograph and also that you call yourself sound design, so sorry If this is oftopic, anyway I don't see much activity here.

Comment: Hi Lerian, We appreciate your question, It's quite interesting actually, but as you're asking about algorithms and digital design, this is a better fit for [dsp.se]. If you have a question more [on-topic](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, don't hesitate to ask. If you're unsure, you can ask in [chat]. Thanks!